# Is it possible to deploy a nestjs microservice backend on a kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nestjs

Hello intelligent stackoverflow people,
i am trying to deploy my microservice backend developed with nestjs on Kubernetes.
But i don´t know how to do it or even find a tutorial that shows me how to.
I found an article talking about a similar case using Kafka as the event-streaming-service.

https://limascloud.com/2022/03/22/nestjs-on-kubernetes-kubernetes-for-developers/

Instead of Kafka i used the native event based communication provided by the framework described in the docs. It is some basic topic based publish-subscribe mechanism.
Does that prohibit the use of Kubernetes. Do i need to use some kind of external communication software?
I am really confused at the moment and dont know if we/i made an error since the start.

Comment: nest is a node js server, so anything nodejs supports is possible, I'm not sure what you mean by native communication, but nest js documents some common transporters that you can use in the [microservices tab](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics) and also how to create a custom transporter. After this it is a matter of building the environment around kubernetes and making the connections

Comment: with native communication i meant the inbuild event-based-communication. Not the custom transporters. I don´t really understand which communication technology to use to let the services communicate. Since Kubernetes needs to be able to proxy all communication, as far as i understand. The lack of articles online tackling this problem made me think it might be not possible.

Comment: I think that event bus is only within the same node js execution instance, you need something external for the pods to be able to communicate to each other. To chose which one, you can start on what your cloud provider offers, In kubernetes I also used rabbitMq, which had it's own deployment in k8s and everything was kept inside

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the post you mentioned. You should be able to use the event-streaming-service, but it's a different scenario than the one I represent in the post.

In the post, the pods are connecting to a Kafka service that is running outside of the Kubernetes network, but in your scenario, the pods need to be able to connect to one another inside the Kubernetes network.

If you are planning to use two separate services, I would recommend using an external broker. If you plan to use the default mechanism, make sure to set the host and port configuration for one of the pods. Lets say api is just going to produce, so set its configuration to the pod name and port of the worker. Let me know if it works. I would start trying to make it work on your local env before going to Kubernetes.